# Thunderbird pop-up notifications

Tags: debian, email, gnome3, notifications, thunderbird

I have Debian 8 as my operating system with GNOME 3.

I want to use Thunderbird as my desktop email client. I would like to receive emails without have Thunderbird always open. I was thinking about have some kind of daemon process to get pop-pup notifications ...

Is it possible? How can I do it?

If not... is there some alternative to do what I want?

Comment: Haven't tried Mailnag, but it sounds like what you want: [1. Daemon](https://github.com/pulb/mailnag) [2. Gnome Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/886/mailnag/)